# Are BEGIN/END needed in SQL script?

Tags: sql, t-sql, syntax, sql-server-2008-r2

Are BEGIN/END needed in SQL scripts (in general) or is it fine to replace them with { and }

Example:

```
IF DB_ID('comics') IS NOT NULL        
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Database exists - dropping the comics database.';
        DROP DATABASE comics;
    END
```

VS

```
IF DB_ID('comics') IS NOT NULL        
{
    PRINT 'Database exists - dropping the comics database.';
    DROP DATABASE comics;
}
```

I am using MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: What database are you using? What's needed depends on the DBMS (syntax is different between them).

Comment: [DB_ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186274.aspx) is TSQL

Comment: I've updated my question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Test it for yourself, and see ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [`IF...ELSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx) shows:

```
IF Boolean_expression 
     { sql_statement | statement_block } 
[ ELSE 
     { sql_statement | statement_block } ]
```

However, the [Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx) page shows:

```
{ } (braces)    Required syntax items. Do not type the braces.
```

So, the braces aren't something that you can enter in your code, but instead are simply showing that there is exactly *one* `sql_statement` or `statement_block` required in an `IF` statement. (Of course, a `statement_block` can contain multiple `sql_statement`s as long as you use `BEGIN` and `END` around them.)

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`BEGIN...END`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225998%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for statement blocks. [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Never heard about {} in SQL.
SQL 92 specification uses BEGIN END.
I think BEGIN END is the only option.